# Custom nested iterations in Pelican with Jinja

Tags: jinja2, pelican

I would like to use Pelican+Jinja to generate a static webpage that is generated from structured data. In particular, I have `article` objects (each is represented by a Markdown file), and `author` objects (same). An article metadata includes `authors: [author_a, author_b]` list. From here, it would be easier to explain what I want to achieve by giving a simple example.

Suppose I have two authors, **Sophie** and **Oliver**, and two articles, **Foo** and **Bar**.
Foo has an author list `[Sophie]` and Bar has an author list `[Sophie, Oliver]`. Sophie has `url: sophie.com` and Oliver has `url: oliver.com` in their metadata. I want the output to be

```
<ul>
  <li>Foo, by <a href='sophie.com'>Sophie</a></li>
  <li>Bar, by <a href='sophie.com'>Sophie</a> and <a href='ollie.com'>Ollie</a></li>
</ul>
```

What I know how to do:

```
<ul>
    {% for p in articles %}
    <li class='paper'>
        {{ p.title }},
        by {{ p.authors }}
    </li>
    {% endfor %}
</ul>
```

This outputs a list of "articles" taken from my "contents" folder (not sure about the order). But I am not sure how to let it read author data from other files (and I am also not sure where to put these files).

Can Pelican handle this scenario, or am I stretching it too much?